# OpenCV putText in Python - Error after array manipulation

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

**SHORT**

I want to write text into an image. I am, however, unable to understand the following behavior:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
# create an image
img = np.ones((512,512,3), dtype = np.uint8)
# create an image container (I have to do this as I cycle through many folder and collect images)
img_container = np.zeros((512,512,3,5), dtype = np.uint8)
# send img to the container array
img_container[:,:,:,0] = img[:,:,:]

# I can add text to the original image
cv2.putText(img, 'Hello World', (10,500), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255),2 )
cv2.imshow('img', img)

# When I retrieve the img again..
img_from_container = img_container[:,:,:,0]
# ..I am unable to do so however
cv2.putText(img_from_container, 'Hello World', (10,500), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255),2 )

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)
```

**LONG**

I do not understand the difference between the two variables (img and img_from_container) as they both are `dtype = np.uint8`, they both have the same shape when testing with `img.shape` and when I compare them with `img==img_from_container` I get all true.

Obviously I am missing something. I would be very grateful for any hints and suggestions on where else these two variables differ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the following line solves the problem

```
img_from_container = img_container[:,:,:,0].copy()
```

`np.copy()` makes it clear to make another copy of the data, then opencv is able to write to that array. The previous code gets a view from a higher dimensional numpy array, where `putText()` failed to modify.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks, also for the clear explanation!